# C++ or Rcpp: comparison of two vectors without loop

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am a novice in C++ and Rcpp, and I am wondering how to compare each element of two different vectors without loop at one time.

My goal is to change the element of `v1` by referencing other vector.`

Current code is

```
v1 = {6,7,8,9,10}
v2 = {2,4,6,8,10}
v3 = {a,b,a,b,c}
v4 = {0,0,0,0,0}
v5 = {a,b,c}
v6 = {1,2,3}

for (i in 1:5){
  if (v1[i] > v2[i]){
    for (j in 1:3){
      if (v5[j] == v3[i]){
        v4[i] = v2[i] + v6[j]
          if (v1[i] > v4[i]){
            v1[i] = v4[i]
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result sould be

```
v1 = {3,6,7,9,10}
```

In fact, `v1, v2, v3, v4` and `v5, v6` are the different `dataframe` in R. Each element of `v1` is compared to `v2`. If an element `i` in `v1` is larger than `i` element in `v2`, the element of `v1` becomes a sum of `i` element of `v1` and element of `v6` by corresponding `v3` & `v5`. Then the newly estimated value `v4[i]` is compared to `v1[i]`.

I have ta large number of cases in `v1~v5` and `v5~v6`. In this case, using `loop` takes a long time. Is it possible to compare the different vectors without loop? or how to estimate and reference the other vector's element?

Comment: Can you expand on your requirement? What are you comparing, and what are you doing with the result? An example, with expected outcome is always helpful for others to see what you're doing.

Comment: Is this a real problem or a homework assignment?  If it is a homework assignment, then what are the parameters?  Recursion can be used to avoid "loops", but it is not clear why you are trying to avoid loops.

Comment: Your code sample produces no output.  If the first two vectors are equivalent, it seems your goal is to never execute the comparison between v1 and v3?  Do you want to return an indicator that v2 is the first vector equivalent to v1?

Comment: I am really sorry for the confusion in my question. I add more information and goal in my current problem. I am a postgraduate in the social science, and this is a problem of my research. I am trying to estimate the travel time between different spatial areals. However, I have no idea about how to avoid loop in Rcpp or C++ currently. In R, it could be easily esimated, but takes a long time when I tried due to a large number of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see the need to use Rcpp or C++ here. The way I understand your requirements, you are trying to manipulate two sets of equal length vectors. For a "set of equal length" vectors one normally uses a `data.frame` or one of its extensions. Here I am using base R, `data.table` and `dplyr` with `tibble`. See for yourself which syntax you prefer. Generally speaking, `data.table` will most likely be faster for large data sets.

Setup data:

```r
v1 <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
v2 <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
v3 <- c("a","b","a","b","c")
v5 <- c("a","b","c")
v6 <- c(1,2,3)
```

Base R:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
df2 <- data.frame(v5, v6)

df1 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "v3", by = "v5")
df1$v4 <- df1$v2 + df1$v6
df1$v1 <- ifelse(df1$v1 > df1$v2 & df1$v1 > df1$v4, df1[["v4"]], df1[["v1"]])
df1
#>   v3 v1 v2 v6 v4
#> 1  a  3  2  1  3
#> 2  a  7  6  1  7
#> 3  b  6  4  2  6
#> 4  b  9  8  2 10
#> 5  c 10 10  3 13
```

`data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(v1, v2, v3, key = "v3")
dt2 <- data.table(v5, v6, key = "v5")

dt1[dt2, v4 := v2 + v6]
dt1[v1 > v2 & v1 > v4, v1 := v4]
dt1
#>    v1 v2 v3 v4
#> 1:  3  2  a  3
#> 2:  7  6  a  7
#> 3:  6  4  b  6
#> 4:  9  8  b 10
#> 5: 10 10  c 13
```

`dplyr`:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
t1 <- tibble(v1, v2, v3)
t2 <- tibble(v5, v6)
t1 %>% 
  inner_join(t2, by = c("v3" = "v5")) %>%
  mutate(v4 = v2 + v6) %>%
  mutate(v1 = case_when(
    v1 > v2 & v1 > v4 ~ v4,
    TRUE ~ v1
  ))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>      v1    v2 v3       v6    v4
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3     2 a         1     3
#> 2     6     4 b         2     6
#> 3     7     6 a         1     7
#> 4     9     8 b         2    10
#> 5    10    10 c         3    13
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

The general idea is always the same:

- join the two tables on the character column
- create new column `v4` as sum of `v2` and `v6`
- update `v1` to the value of `v4` where `v1 > v2` and `v1 > v4`

Note that base R and `data.table` do not preserve the order, so it would make more sense to put the output into an additional column.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I had no idea about data.table and tibble! Again thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Suralira.K You are welcome. See the updated answer for a base R solution. BTW, the customary way to say "thank you" on SO is to upvote and/or accept answers.

Comment: Sorry for my late acceptance for your answers. By the way, could you let me know one more thing? Although I did not include in the above question, I should repeat the above function. It is possible to utilze the above codes in the for loop. However, I have about 300,000 cases, the for loop should be repeated about 300,000. When I tried, it takes a long time. Because of this repetation, I considered Rcpp. Could you let me know to make it faster by using your answer? I tried for loop by using data.table, but it still takes a long time than Rcpp.

Comment: @Suralira.K This is difficult to assess without more details. How large is one case? In my experience typical tasks like joining and grouping for **large** datasets are fastest with data.table. Things might be different for many smaller datasets. In such a case I would try to combine the datasets and use grouping.